# how can i create a windowmanager which only shows in my application

Tags: android, types, window-managers

I have tried to create a window manager like this:
`WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);`

The type of the window manager's LayoutParams is `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`

The window manager shows not only on my application but also on desktop. Now I want to create a window manager only shows on my application.

I've tried in some ways:

1. use 'TYPE_APPLICATION' type.It'll cause WindowManger$BadToken exception.
2. use `this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)`. In this way, when my activity is not active, the window manager disappears. But if the screen jumps to desktop from my application, the icons on the desktop all disappear!!!

Do you have any idea on my problem ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've solved my problem just now:
use `TYPE_APPLICATION` type and use `this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)` not `getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)` to create the window manager.